# ImportError: No module named b - Python

Tags: python

I was stuck with a code in python. But in simple form it looks like this

`a.py` looks like this

```
import b

def hello():
  print "hello"

print "a.py"
print hello()
print b.hi()
```

and b.py looks like this

```
def hi():
  print "hi"
```

a.py , i get an error. I know a couple of questions that address circular dependancies. But this is not that case correct?
TIA - Edited

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Are you sure you don't get the `ImportError` when you try to run `a.py`?  (As opposed to `b.py`.)

Comment: Where are `a.py` and `b.py`? In the same directory?

Comment: More importantly, are they in your current working directory? If you try to run `a.py` by typing `python ~/my/programs/a.py`, you're going to have problems. And if you try to run it by double-clicking it in Finder/Explorer/Nautilus/etc., that's effectively what you're doing.

Comment: @karthikr this is what i get " import b
ImportError: No module named b" when i run a.py

Comment: @5gon12eder: That was a typo. You are correct. The error shows up with a.py and not b.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a problem like this before and it was because I did not have an `__init__.py` in the same directory as the module/package I was trying to import. You need that file in order to import a package even if it's empty.

Comment: This is only needed for *packages* (as you say) but not for *modules*.  Since the OP only has a single file, it's a module rather than a package.  And even then, the file should be named `__init__.py` (which is a markdown error).

Comment: You really, really should not turn your top-level source directory into a package.